# scapy sending packets until ctrl+c not working

Tags: python, scapy, keyboardinterrupt

First I tried running this:

```
from scapy.all import *
while True:
    send([ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc="192.168.1.60")])
```

I sends 9 packets then stops. I wanted it to run until I press ctrl+c.
I have a list of ip `["192.168.1.7","192.168.1.12","192.168.1.32","192.168.1.223"]`
I tried running:

```
from scapy.all import *
   while True:
       for ip in mylist:
           send([ARP(op=ARP.who_has, psrc="192.168.1.60")])
```

It still sends 9 packets and stop. I would like to know how to send packets until I press ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use:

```
 send(ARP(op=1,psrc='172.16.16.255'),loop=1)
```

It should keep going until you hit Ctrl+C.

Ok.  I edited it to iterate over your list:

```
mylist = ('192.168.1.12','192.168.1.32','192.168.1.223')
while True:
    for i in mylist:
        send(ARP(op=1,psrc='192.168.1.60',pdst=i))
```